# Add button in sap.m.list row

Tags: sapui5

I want to add buttons to each row in my sap.m.List. On that button I want to open a popup to display further details without navigating to another page.

Any code snippet or examples out there how I can add buttons to each row and bind them to fetch data from another model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the `StandardListItem` you need a `CustomListItem`. There you can add any control you like:

```xml
<List headerText="Custom Content" items="{path: '/ProductSet'}" >
    <CustomListItem>
        <HBox>
            <Label text="{ProductName}"/>
            <Button text="More Infos" click="onPressMoreInfos" />
        </HBox>
    </CustomListItem>
</List>
```

I think the tricky part here is the binding. One `CustomListItem` is bound to a single entity of your set. If you add a `Button` to your `CustomListItem` (or any other control) they are also automatically bound to the specific entity.

So in your click handler you can do the following:

```js
onPressMoreInfos: function(oEvent) {
    var oButton = oEvent.getSource();

    // if your model has a name, don't forget to pass it as a parameter
    var oContext = oButton.getBindingContext();

    // create the popover, either here or in a new method
    var oPopover = this.getTheInfoPopover();
    // if your model has a name, don't forget to pass it as the second parameter
    oPopover.setBindingContext(oContext);
}
```

Then your Popover has the same binding information as the list item and you can access every property of the specific entity.

Comment: sorry Marc, another short question, is there a way I could configure an hover action instead of press/click event? because in the xml tags I couldn''t add a hover action

Comment: my popover should be opened

Comment: Doesn't sound like good usability, but it's possible with `attachBrowserEvent` if you can access every button via code. Answer is too long for a comment, you should ask a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

1. Try below code to add a button to each row, in your XML view:

```html
<columns>
  <Column id="userNameColumn">
    <Text text="userNameLabelText" />
  </Column>
  <Column id="buttonColumn">
    <Text text="Button" />
  </Column>
</columns>
<items>
  <ColumnListItem>
    <cells>
      <Input value="{UserName}"/>
    </cells>
    <Button id="buttonId" icon="sap-icon://add" press="handleResponsivePopoverPress"></Button>
  </ColumnListItem>
</items>
```

2. Controller to handle button press, see example here
   https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.ResponsivePopover/preview

Comment: Nice answer. Moreover, you posted a good answer in the travel site for that Boeing and also a helpful comment in my German question. For that, I would like to link you to the [God of Time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318910/time-for-some-more-swag/319020#319020) post for the 10 years of SO, as a thank-you gesture. This comment will selfdestruct around some time...

Answer (score 0):

You can use sap.m.CustomListItem as a template for items aggregation. There is a sample [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.CustomListItem/code). You can add any control to the item.